# Flash AS3 Custom Colour Strobe Animation

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, web

I have been working on a website for a while now [(http://strobepage.com/](http://strobepage.com/) ATTENTION: do not click if you are suffering of epillepsy)..
Basically the idea is that the viewer can chose between different strobe illusions and colours..

I got thinking, and I thought, I can make things a hell of a lot easier by allowing users to select the 2+ colours in a strobe animation instead of me making a number of different specific animations that have various different colours..  Possibly, there could be different SWF's that the user can pick from (on the home page) and  these different SWF's could all have a different number of colour rotations in the strobe, for example 3 repeating colours..  I realise that this would only be relevant if its not possible to integrate everything into a single file..

Anyway, I have tried and tried many methods and I cant get anything to work.. It needs to work with what i have..  a base strobe with a "fullscreen" button, launching the strobe into fulscreen, then I want the user to be greeted with a screen with a GUI that allows them to select the colour(s) and then click to proceed..  also maybe a colour selector that is present while the strobe is running..

Any suggestions will have to work with the functions and controls i already have in place, and if you can suggest the AS to use aswell, that would be awsome..  but just a bunch of ideas would be great also.

Thanks, I look forward to reading some interesting ideas ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add some warning for people with epilepsy to not click on that link. People might get hurt.

As for your question, you can always color movieclips using this:

```
var c:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform();
c.color = (0xFF0000); // should be red
myMovieclip.transform.colorTransform = c;
```

This would require your animations to be based on Movieclips and not 'just' tweens. As for tweens, you might be able to put the whole thing into a Movieclip and color it, all depending on how you did it in the first place.

Comment: ok I like that idea, it should work well with what I'v got, Until ill get around to putting in a brief epilepsy notice (that obviously appears before it starts strobing, in adition to the one i have now) but for now, lets just hope epileptic sufferers stray away from clicking a link called "strobe"..

Thanks for your tip, Ill give it a shot ;)